# LaTeX finds .cls file but not .sty file in ~/texmf directory

Tags: texmf, packages

I'm writing a paper that depends on a file `elsarticle.cls` and also a file `clrscode3e.sty` (they're for two different things - not related).  I have placed both files in my `~/texmf` directory.  When I remove anything in my .tex file dependent on `clrscode3e.sty` and compile with LaTeX, everything is fine and from the output formatting i can see that `elsarticle.cls` has clearly been recognised.  When I add something which depends on `clrscode3e.sty`, I get "File clrscode3e.sty not found".  To verify that I hadn't mistyped anything, I tried moving clrscode3e.sty into the same directory as the .tex file being compiled and everything worked fine.  Why would LaTeX recognise a `.cls` file in my `~/texmf` directory but not a `.sty` file?

Comment: Put it in `~/texmf/tex/latex/SOMENAME` and run `texhash`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows and other previous related questions.

Comment: Could it be the case that the cls is already installed in your distribution and it is read from the main tex-tree rather than you local one?

Comment: @Martin H: AFAIK the user directory should come first, but this is of course a matter of configuration.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: True, but maybe not in if the cls is not in the correct folder within the local tree. That is what I implied

Comment: @Martin H: The folder shouldn't make a difference as along it was not used when the file was referenced, e.g. like `\input{folder/file}`.

Comment: Look in the log file (not the output) to determine from where `elsarticle.cls` is being loaded.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: What Martin H. means is that the local cls and sty are both in a wrong folder which is not searched, and that a second version of the cls exists in a correct location.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely answer here is that neither file is being loaded from `~/texmf`, but that the `.cls` file is also installed correctly in the main TeX tree. The way to work this out is to look at the `.log` file which TeX produces. Each file loaded will include the location it was loaded from, so a quick search for the relevant files should reveal where they are loaded from.

In general, TeX will find any `.cls` or `.sty` file inside `~/texmf/tex/latex`, although you may need to run `texhash` before this happens. (Recent versions of TeX Live do not require you to run `texhash` on your local tree, whereas older ones do.)